How do I query rows of only the max value record of unique IDs within a table?
I have a table of data with application records where I would like to see only the latest entry submitted. Some unique_ids have 1 application records, while other unique_ids have 15 records. If a unique_id has only one record, I only want to see 1 record. If a unique_id has 15 records, I only want to see the 15th record. If 2 records, I only want to see the 2nd record. If 3 records, I only want to see the 3rd record, and so on.
I tried the below, however this eliminates all unique_id records with only 1 instance, any unique_ids with more than 1 record works as desired:
select unique_id, column1, column2, column3
from table 1
inner join table 2 on X1 = X2
group by column1, column2, column3
having count(*)> 1
order by column1;


How do you know it's the latest entry?

@Eric I wondered this at first, too (it's in my answer), but looking again it seems like he might be using column1. But definitely not clear.

The trick is relational databases have no concept at all of any insert or natural order for the records. Therefore, to know which is the "lastest entry" for a given unique_id, you must be able to define it in terms of data in the columns. This could be a datetime column or sequential column, but you MUST do this.
If you can't determine this from the data, the database can and sometimes will give you different results from the same data for different runs of the same SQL. It might seem like you always get the rows the order they are stored on disk or via primary key, but this is misleading. There are a number of things that can impact this at odd times.
Assuming you can do this, the solution will involve the row_number() window function, which I demonstrate below using the imaginary column1 to decide which record is most recent.
WITH numbered AS (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() over (partition by unique_id order by column1 desc) rn
    FROM [table]
)
SELECT unique_id, column1, column2, column3
FROM numbered
WHERE rn = 1


Thank you for your response and the extra context of how this should work. My apologies for missing this piece, but I do have a sequential column for application_no. Using my example, column1 = application_no, listing the number of each application submitted. There are no columns that have dates.
